# Docker daemon.json --privileged

Tags: docker, elevated-privileges

Is there a way to modify my docker `daemon.json` so containers start in privileged mode without requiring the run flag?

Comment: Anyone care to comment why they voted to close this? I believe it's a legitimate question and is not a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe because your question is best suited for superuser.com

Comment: I disagree with that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no option in the `daemon.json` file to do this. If you find the commands tedious to type or error prone, consider using a `docker-compose.yml` file to define how you want to run the container.

Comment: I'm using Amazon SageMaker, which executes the run command so that I do not have direct access to add additional flags. For context, without adding this privileged flag, Horovod/MPI spam my logs with read errors: https://github.com/horovod/horovod/issues/503